# Return JSON array as response using Google Cloud Endpoints Framework in Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am using Google Endpoints Framework with Python (https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python) and have been building REST APIs with it.

I am able to return JSON object (dictionaries) in the response like:

```
{
    "items":[
        {
            "id": "brand_1_id",
            "name": "Brand 1"
        },
        {
            "id": "brand_2_id",
            "name": "Brand 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I am not able to return a JSON array (list) as response like:

[
    {
        "id": "brand_1_id",
        "name": "Brand 1"
    },
    {
        "id": "brand_2_id",
        "name": "Brand 2"
    }
]

Following are the code snippets I have been using to return the response

**Following are the classes created to send a response:**

```
class BrandResponse(messages.Message):
    id=messages.StringField(1, required=True)
    brandName = messages.StringField(2, required=True)
    brandEmail=messages.StringField(3, required=True)
    brandPhone=messages.StringField(4,required=True)
    brandAddress=messages.StringField(5,required=True)
    brandCity=messages.StringField(6,required=True)
    brandState=messages.StringField(7,required=True)
    brandCountry=messages.StringField(8,required=True)
    brandPostalCode=messages.StringField(9,required=True)

class MultipleBrandResponse(messages.Message):
    items=messages.MessageField(BrandResponse,1,repeated=True)
```

**Following is the method that processes the request:**

```
@endpoints.method(
        MULTIPLE_BRAND_PAGINATED_CONTAINER,
        MultipleBrandResponse,
        path='brand',
        http_method='GET',
        name='Get Brands',
        audiences=firebaseAudience
    )
    def getBrands(self,request):
        brandResponse=[]

        query = BrandDB.query()
        brands = query.fetch(request.limit, offset=request.start)
        for brand in brands:
            brandResponse.append(BrandResponse(
            id=brand.key.urlsafe(),
            brandName=brand.name,
            brandAddress=brand.address,
            brandCity=brand.city,
            brandState=brand.state,
            brandCountry=brand.country,
            brandPostalCode=brand.postalCode,
            brandPhone=brand.phone,
            brandEmail=brand.email))

        print("Brand count: "+str(brandResponse.count))

        if len(brandResponse) == 0:
            raise endpoints.NotFoundException("No brands")

        return MultipleBrandResponse(items=brandResponse)
```

Any idea how to return JSON array directly rather than wrapping in side a key inside a JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework is designed around returning Protocol Buffer messages, not JSON. It's possible you may have specified a message which that dict structure matches; hard to say without seeing your code.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the actual code as well.

Comment: You are not using JSON objects. You are using Protocol Buffer messages; MultipleBrandResponse is a message with one field, which contains a list of BrandResponse messages. The "root" of a Protocol Buffer response must be a single message, not a list of messages.

Comment: Think you are right. So using Protocol Buffers and creating a REST API, there is no way to get multiple messages and hence JSON array as a response.

Comment: That's correct. I'm the lead dev on this Framework so I'm adding your request as a feature request for a possible future version.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Car(messages.Message):
    brand = messages.StringFeild(1)
    color = messages.StringFeild(2)

class ResponseCars(messages.Message):
    cars = messages.MessageField(Car,1, repeated = True)

@endpoints.api(name='mycar', version='v1')
class MyCar(remote.Service):
    @endpoints.method(
        message_types.VoidMessage,
        ResponseCars,
        path='getCars',
        http_method='GET',
        name='get_cars')
    def get_cars(self, request):
        cars = [Car(brand='bmw', color = 'black'), Car(brand='toyota', color='white')]
        return ResponseCars(cars = cars)

#ref : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/protorpc/messages/messagefieldclass
```

Comment: Please add some description